# How to convert the allocation of values in a column, into values between 1 to -1

Tags: excel, math

In Excel i've got column A values that are between 3-21. I want to convert them in column B, in order to have the first value 3 = 1 and the last value 21 = -1. Is this possible?

Thank you!

Comment: Yes.  What have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried this code in column B :"value in column A / 21 " and then in other column, i try this :"(value in column B * 2 )-1".

Comment: So... why does `3` correspond to `1`? And why does `21` correspond to `-1`? What's the result for `4` or `10` or `20`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In B1 enter:

**=(-A1+12)/9**   and copy down